# contact form 7 spam error

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

Hi Here I using contact form 7 for my inquiry, and here all my mails are going to spam folder.
Here I using google captcha for security but still the messages are going to spam folder and also I tried contact form honey pot but nothing happening

Comment: Have you configured SMTP setting?

Comment: Do you mean that non-spam contacts are going to spam folder, or that you are getting a lot of spam? If real contacts are going to spam folder, it's your mail program's problem, not the contact form's. In your mail program mark the messages as non-spam.

Comment: hi @purvik7373 No I didn't configure SMTP

Comment: @JJJ but here in my all website showing the same error..Before it is going to mail folder but recently the mail from all websites are going to spam folder and when I change the mail id the mail is not going to specified account

Comment: Would you please install https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ plugin and configure all setting?

Comment: @purvik7373 sure dear

Comment: @purvik7373 Here I install and activate wp-mail-smtp , But still my messages are going to spam folder

Comment: Like I said, it has nothing to do with your Wordpress installation or the contact form. Your email software or the email provider has decided for whatever reason that the emails coming from your site are spam. Make a filter in the email software that doesn't mark those emals spam. @purvik7373 if the mails are coming through it means that the SMTP settings are ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sites like [mail-tester](https://www.mail-tester.com/) and [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) to see if there are problems with you email settings. Sometimes it helps to add a [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) or [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record to your hosting DNS settings.